# PHP MYSQL > search for username and echo a columns data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a simple php script that will look through my database for a username and echo a column. The column I want to echo is a date.

I'm making a script that checks if the date assigned to the user is todays date.

```
$datenow = date("Y-m-d");
$user = $_SESSION['username'];

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database name');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT accessfrom FROM users WHERE username = $user");

// Now I need a simple way to check if the results date = $datenow(from above)

mysql_close(); //Make sure to close out the database connection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use MySQL. It is deprecated. So, use mysqli_.

Presumably, username is a string. So, you have a mismatch in your comparisons. The naive solution is to add single quotes:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT accessfrom FROM users WHERE username = '$user'");
```

The correct solution is to use mysqli_ and use parameters for passing in values. This not only solves your problem. It also prevents SQL injection attacks, and teaches you how to correctly write queries.

Comment: this answer does not answer the question asked about the date.

Answer (score 1):

First you should use pdo or something.

```
foreach($result as $v){

   if ($v['date'] === $datenow){
     //your have a hit
   }

}
```

but you should do it in your query (where date = $datenow) or something

Comment: Yea, that what I was trying to do but it wasn't working correctly. I'm working on it right now. I'll let you know!